# SYMFONY FORM isClicked() issue (depending Browser) when mixed with JavaScript - JQuery: event.preventDefault() and event.target.submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, symfony

**The goal:**

I want on a Symfony FORM to have **two submit buttons**. 1st one would be used to validate the form, the **2nd submit button would be used to get away from the form**.

By default the fields of the form use the `required` check before submitting, which means that prior to use the 2nd Submit, the `required` attributes need to be turned off on DOM `<input>`. I do that by using some JQuery, `event.preventDefault()`, I turn off the `required` on each `<input>` and then do an `event.target.submit()`.

Then on my Symfony side I expect to catch the button that had been clicked by using the `$form->has([button name])->isClicked()` function.

**The issue:**

I have noticed that depending on the browser, the $form->has([button name])->isClicked() doesn't work if some JavaScript with `event.preventDefault()` and `event.target.submit()` had been used.

On chrome (Version 51.0.2704.103 m) I get (isClicked = 1 or true):
[image]

On firefox (Version 47.0) or Microsoft EDGE 25.* I get (isClicked = false):
[image]

**The code:**

[**The full code is at the following github**](https://github.com/nyluje/symfony_form_test_isclicked).

*Emphasis on the code:*

In /src/AppBundle/Form/FormType.php you'll find, the code that manages the JavaScript to hold on the `Submit`, turnoff the `required` and resume the `Submit`:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

    $builder
    ->add('field1',EmailType::class, array('label'=>'Form Field 1'))
    ->add('submit',SubmitType::class,array('label'=>'Submit Form'))
  ->add('get_away_from_form',SubmitType::class,array(
    'label'=>'Get away from form',
    'attr'=>array(
    'onclick'=>'{
      //IF THE USER CLICK THE NOT_SUBMIT BUTTON THE REQUIRED FIELD ARE DISABLED BEFORE THE SUBMIT HAPPENS
     // Here is the part where are done (see GITHUB code for details): 
     ////`event.preventDefault()`,
     //// turn off the `required` on each `<input>`
     //// and then do an `event.target.submit()`.

    }'
    )
    ));
  }
```

In /src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php you'll find, the check on $form->get('get_away_from_form')->isClicked():

```
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->has('get_away_from_form')){
        if($form->get('get_away_from_form')->isClicked() == 1){
            $isClicked = 'It works as expected: $form->get(get_away_from_form)->isClicked() = '.$form->get('get_away_from_form')->isClicked();
        } else {
            $isClicked = 'It DOESN\'T work as expected: $form->get(get_away_from_form)->isClicked() = '.$form->get('get_away_from_form')->isClicked();
        }
    }
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case one needs to use `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `event.preventDefault()`.

And there is no need for the  event.target.submit().

Now, my JS function associated to the onclick looks like this:

```
'onclick'=>'{
      //IF THE USER CLICK THE NOT_SUBMIT BUTTON THE REQUIRED FIELD ARE DISABLED BEFORE THE SUBMIT HAPPENS
      e= \'form\';

      $(e).submit(
        function(event){
             event.stopPropagation(); 
        }
      );  

      function disableReq(e){
        var disableReqDef = $.Deferred();
        var disableReqDefProm = disableReqDef.promise();
        requiredFields = $(e).find(\'[required="required"]\');
        requiredFields.each(function(){
          $(this).attr(\'required\',false);
        }); 

        disableReqDef.resolve();  
        return disableReqDefProm;
      }

      var dr = disableReq(e);

      $.when(
        e,
        dr,
        undefined
      ).done(function(e){

        $(e).submit(function(event){});
      });
    }'
```

Comment: this change means you will keep the normal submission, which is indeed done by clicking on the button. In such case, you should remove `event.target.submit()` to avoid submitting twice. and the question is whether you really need to stop the propagation to other listeners

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a submit button to get away from the form, instead of just using a link to another page ? It would avoid the need to bypass form validation

Comment: "why not a link to another page instead of all this circus"; thanks for that really down to earth comment:) My true wish was to find a ButtonType, detach from the validation rules among all the kind of Type you have available for the Symfony form (you re gonna tell me I could design it myself, please don't :). I think it happens that in the controller (or sub services you make to call inside your controller), I set rules to determine what should be displayed after each button is clicked, hence my cancel button use the SubmitType one. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you really want to use a submit button to cancel things rather than a link pointing to a separate controller, you could use the `formnovalidate` attribute on the button to disable the validation using the native way

Answer (score 0):

Why not use code like the following:

```
if ( $form->get('get_away_from_form')->isClicked() ){
    return $this->redirectToRoute('detourRoute');
}
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
...
```

Or is it that you **MUST** use javascript and/or JQuery in your code. My suggestion is simpler... This is only just a suggestion.

Comment: the Form has `required` attr. on all `input` fields, since 'get_away_from_form' is going to be a SubmitType, I have to unset the `required` (with JQuery) before processing further. I guess your proposition would work if `required` attr. was unset on all `<input>` of the form by default. Thanks for giving new direction in anycase.

Comment: I think to avoid that problem I used `{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}` in my twig file. Or alternately if you can use createFormBuilder instead, then use: `$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null, ['attr'=>['novalidate'=>'novalidate']])`. I don't know if it can be used in buildForm.This prevents the HTML5 Validation and the 'required' attribute.